# I want to tar X directory not including its parents

Tags: directory, tar

```
tar cvf /var/lib/backup/sample.tar /home/user/.project
```

However, when I extract, I get its parents as well

```
/backup/
  - /home/
     - /user/
        - .project/
```

This tar commands does it job because it doesn't include anything else in its parents (other folders under `user` for example).

I want to do this programmatically, so changing the current working directory into `/home/user/` is not really an option. 
Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can either use the `-C` option to change into the `/home/user` directory before tarring or use `--strip-components 2` on extraction.

```
tar cvfC /var/lib/backup/sample.tar /home/user .project
#                              Note the space ^
```

```
tar cvf /var/lib/backup/sample.tar /home/user/.project
tar Cxf /backup /var/lib/backup/sample.tar --strip-components 2
```

Comment: +1 cool .. I just found the `-C` switch when I was looking through the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tar), but couldn't make sense of it .. sounded to me more like it would be used during untar. Learned something new.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks. The C option works flawlessly. Thank you!

Comment: I couldn't get it working like this. According reading https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC118 I was successful with following form: tar cvf /var/lib/backup/sample.tar -C /home/user .project

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you `cd` to the toplevel directory that you want to create `tar` file of, you shouldn't have this problem. I.e.,

`cd` to `user` and the `tar` up `.project` .. you can specify the destination for the tar file in the `/var/...`  as before.

Or is there a reason you don't want to/can't `cd` to `user`?

Comment: Yes. That would be one solution. Thanks. But I hope there is a better way? I want to deal wtih this programmatic ally, and I don't want to issue `os.chdir(base_dir)` in my code all the time :) so it would be nice if there's a way out of this. Thanks

Comment: @User007 Ah .. ok, I see. You may want to update your question to include that requirement. Nice user id by the way :)

Comment: Thanks. Yes. I've just updated my question. Oh it's to hide my identity...

Comment: @User007 love the 007 part .. and looks like you are working in Python too (which is another one of my favorites)

Comment: :) Yes. All right our friend `Kevin` helped me out with the right command. So I will give him the tick. But I upvoted you. Thanks!